# Which serial device is linked to console(Linux)?

Tags: c++, linux, console, serial-port, tty

I want to find out which serial device (/dev/ttyS0-X) is linked to console so I can skip them from opening to prevent concurrent problems. This should be realized within a generic C/C++ function, that checks all tty devices and returns a selection of available (not linked to the console) serial devices.

Is there a way to get such information like from the Linux Kernel or the C/C++ file library?

Comment: "is linked to console" - do you mean "has something plugged in at the other end"?

Comment: I mean that a device file of a serial device, esp /dev/ttyAMA2 can be connected to the shells console. So if you open two consoles and writes something on the one console to the serial device (`echo "something" > /dev/ttyAMA2`) it will also appear in the other console.

Comment: On Linux boot it is signaled by this line (here is /dev/ttyAMA2 connected to the console): `starting pid 398, tty '/dev/console': '/bin/login root </dev/ttyAMA2'`

Answer (score 0):

try tty command
it shows /dev/pts/0
if u open another console terminal it wil be /dev/pts/1..It shows the no terminal no you are in
U can connect the devices in shell console